# Initialise a Swing JPanel with Another

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I have a problem initialising a JPanel .Here is my code :`

```
    JPanel    canvas = new JPanel();
    JPanel can = canvas;
    System.out.println("COMPONENTS 1 :" + canvas.getComponentCount());
    System.out.println("COMPONENTS 1 :" + can.getComponentCount());
    JTextField txt = new JTextField();
    txt.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 30);
    can.add(txt);
    System.out.println("COMPONENTS 2 :" + canvas.getComponentCount());
    System.out.println("COMPONENTS 2 :" + can.getComponentCount());
```

`

THE OUTPUT IS :

```
COMPONENTS 1 :0
COMPONENTS 1 :0
COMPONENTS 2 :1
COMPONENTS 2 :1
```

What i want :

```
COMPONENTS 1 :0
COMPONENTS 1 :0
COMPONENTS 2 :0
COMPONENTS 2 :1
```

Answer (score 2):

With the line 
    JPanel can = canvas;

you're not creating a new JPanel object. You're making can, point to the same JPanel object that canvas points too. Canvas is simply a pointer to the memory address of JPanel. Effectively, can and canvas are the exact same JPanel. You want to create a new JPanel instance, if you want to be able to modify them independently.